# Problem creating SQLite trigger

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers

I have a table called `posts` having an `INT` field `posted` and a table `domains` having field `posted` too, this one is supposed to be the sum of a `posted`s of `post`s belonging to a certain `domain`. Whether the post belongs to a domain is determined by a foreign `domain_id` in the table `posts` which links to the `id` in `domains`. I'm trying to create a trigger that would update the `posted` of a domain every time the `posted` is changed for any of its posts. Here's what I was trying:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [update_posted]
AFTER UPDATE OF [posted]
ON posts
BEGIN
UPDATE domains SET posted = posted + NEW.posted - OLD.posted WHERE id = NEW.domain_id 
END
```

which complains about bad syntax near `END`. What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `;` to the end of your update statement.